# How to create a gallery page with categories?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, gallery

I'm a beginner in Wordpress theme development.

I want to create a gallery page that have sorting feature to different categories. 
[Here's an example page that I want to imitate.](http://vus.edu.vn/en/gallery/photo/)

How do I go about creating the custom post type for a Gallery page? Then how can I put the categories selector like that?

Thank you in advance!